# Is it possible to pass stdout to the nodejs worker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-worker-threads

I write a nodejs console application that does some logic that blocks the main thread.

I also want to use [ora terminal spinner](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ora):

```
const sp1 = ora('runnning job 1').start();

job1();

sp1.succeed();

const sp2 = ora('runnning job 2').start();

job2();

sp2.succeed();
....
```

The problem is `ora` is also running on the main thread. So the result is ora is freezing because my jobs are blocking the main thread.

I thought about moving the `ora` into a worker `ora`, but it froze:

```
index.ts:

import path from 'node:path';
import {
  Worker,
  isMainThread,
  parentPort,
  workerData,
} from 'node:worker_threads';

const worker = new Worker(path.resolve(__dirname, 'work'));

work.ts:
import ora from 'ora';

console.log('in worker!!!');
ora().start('working...');
```

I know `ora` takes a stream. is there a way to pass the main thread stdout to the worker?